# difference between _read and fscanf

Tags: visual-c++, scanf

I am trying to read in data from a file and am confused. The file contains three columns of data. With fscanf it is giving the correct values.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt");
double buffer[3];
fscanf(fp,"%lf %lf %lf",&buffer[0],&buffer[1],&buffer[2]);
```

Now I am trying to read the same set of values using _read. This gives me all the wrong values.

```
int fh;
char buffer[50];
_sopen_s( &fh,CStringA(PointFile),_O_RDONLY|_O_BINARY,_SH_DENYNO,0);
_read(fh,buffer,sizeof(double)*3);
```

It will be really helpful if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code snippet reads textual representation of `double`s and converts them. That's what `*scanf` family of functions does.

Example valid input:

```
1.0 2.7182818 3.14159265358
```

The second code snippet reads some (probably 24) bytes from a file, without parsing or conversion. You didn't show how you extract doubles from your buffer. Something like `*(double *)buffer` (to get the first value) would be expected, and it would be right (modulo alignment issues, but it's irrelevant for your platform) if you have a "dump" of 3 platform-specific doubles in your file, created with appropriate `fwrite` or `_write`.

Example valid input (hex dump, assuming 64-bit IEEE floats):

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

(If you were using POSIX read, here would be a warning on the possibility of short reads. However, `_read` and `_s_open` suggest Microsoft CRT, and it doesn't do short reads in binary mode unless the end of file is reached).

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured it out now.